# Real time notification among android app using server in between using FCM or XMPP?

Tags: firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement on communication between 2 android device. When one device triggers a request to another device to do something, the second device starts working until first device ask it to stop.I tried using FCM with only data as notification is not needed.

I have tried Firebase Cloud Messaging but notifications are not consistent i.e some time comes immediately/with 10 min delay/never comes at all.I was using Android simulator.With rest api call also same thing happens. With XMPP i have not tried (even it comes immediately i can not make more than 1000 connection per senderid).I have tried with both use cases with app in background and foreground.

from FCM notification point of view is this delay expected (as it is notification and not real time)?

I am also thinking of using some other XMPP server to have the connection always and send data in real time to achieve this. But don't wanted to spin and scale up/down ejabber kind of server for this kind some small but critical use case.Any pointer would be great !!

Comment: FCM notifications should be close to real time. In particular when sending directly to a device token.

Comment: Depending on the internet speed it either never reaches or come instantaneously . am i missing some thing or it can happen ??